# how do i share a mutable variable between threads?

Tags: multithreading, rust, mutability

i need to have a thread that recursively checks a variable while the main thread changes the variable. however, it appears that with `move`, the variable is not being changes by the lambda in `register`. (i checked and the function works, its just that `move` makes it so i cannot change the original variable)

the code i currently have created:

```rust
use std::io::stdin;
use std::thread;

use enigo::{self, Enigo, MouseControllable};
use enigo::MouseButton;

use livesplit_hotkey::*;


fn main() {
    let mut input = String::new();
    let mut started = false;

    println!("How many clicks per tick? (too many will lag)");

    stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("Unable to read line");

    let input2 = input.trim().parse::<u16>().unwrap();

    for _ in 0 .. input2 {
        thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut enigo = Enigo::new();

            loop {
                if started {
                    println!("clicking"); // debug
                    enigo.mouse_click(MouseButton::Left);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    println!("Press f8 to toggle clicking");

    let hook = Hook::new().unwrap();

    hook.register(Hotkey { key_code: KeyCode::F8, modifiers: Modifiers::empty() },  move || {
        started = !started;
    }).expect("Unable to assign hotkey");

    loop {}
}
```

i know that there are things such as Arc and Mutex, but i'm unsure how to use them correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a static `AtomicBool` in place of `started`:

```rust
use std::io::stdin;
use std::thread;

use enigo::{self, Enigo, MouseControllable};
use enigo::MouseButton;

use livesplit_hotkey::*;

static STARTED: atomic::AtomicBool = atomic::AtomicBool::new(false);

fn main() {
    let mut input = String::new();

    println!("How many clicks per tick? (too many will lag)");

    stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("Unable to read line");

    let input2 = input.trim().parse::<u16>().unwrap();

    for _ in 0 .. input2 {
        thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut enigo = Enigo::new();

            loop {
                if STARTED.load(atomic::Ordering::SeqCst) {
                    println!("clicking"); // debug
                    enigo.mouse_click(MouseButton::Left);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    println!("Press f8 to toggle clicking");

    let hook = Hook::new().unwrap();

    hook.register(Hotkey { key_code: KeyCode::F8, modifiers: Modifiers::empty() },  move || {
        // use xor(true) to emulate "NOT" operation
        // true ^ true -> false
        // false ^ true -> true
        STARTED.fetch_xor(true, atomic::Ordering::SeqCst);
    }).expect("Unable to assign hotkey");

    loop {}
}
```

Note: `Ordering::SeqCst` may not be the ideal atomic ordering for this. You could use one of the less strict orderings, but I'll leave that to you.